# PushTopic not notifying for updates

Tags: apex, pushtopic

I have successfully created a PushTopic through the PHP Force Workbench running locally.  Then, I monitor the results under the 'Streaming Push Topics' feature in Workbench.

Here is the PushTopic:

```
PushTopic pushTopic = new PushTopic();
pushTopic.Name = 'ContactUpdates';
pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT LastName, FirstName, MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingState, MailingPostalCode, Id FROM Contact';
pushTopic.ApiVersion = 37.0;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationCreate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUpdate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUndelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationDelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForFields = 'Referenced';
insert pushTopic;
```

Notice I am explicitly declaring NotifyForOperationUpdate.  When I monitor this stream, I get notifications for the account creations, but not for the account updates.  Specifically, I was updating the LastName and FirstName fields.

When I create a new PushTopic and specificy NotifyForFields as 'All', I am able to see updates.

I can certainly use 'All' with the significant downside of getting updates that do not matter to the application.

**Question 1**: Why does updating FirstName and LastName not work for 'Referenced' fields, but does work for 'All', since the query SELECT clause includes FirstName and LastName?

NOTE: this is not a duplicate of [Streaming API : not getting updates for some standard fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36925/streaming-api-not-getting-updates-for-some-standard-fields) as I am specifying explicit Apex options and for a different API version.  However, the answer may be the same for both (which could be as simple as, "it is a bug in SalesForce Streaming API").

Comment: Nice first question!

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson!  I've worked with StackOverflow a fair amount, so trying to follow same procedures.  Nice to see the community is friendlier on this side ;)

Answer (score 4):

You have to add in your query the `Name` field :

Your query would look like this : `SELECT Name, LastName, FirstName, MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingState, MailingPostalCode, Id FROM Contact`

Then when you update the lastname or firstname it will send a notification.

salesforce documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/pushtopic_queries_compound_fields.htm

Comment: @ryanm you should accept this answer. The official docs referred to clearly states why your update is not firing and how to fix the issue.

Comment: It seems this issue also affects `lead` as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding a where clause (it can be something that is always expected to be true such as created date after 1900)
2. Change NotifyForFields to Select

Comment: Thanks for the ideas!  I am no longer actively working on this project, so it may take some time for me to vet these.  Meanwhile, if anyone in the community can test / vet these and they work, please let me know.

While #1 may work, it is a workaround.  I'm OK with workarounds, so long as they are long-term (won't get munged by an API minor version update) and they fix the glitch.  Seems the glitch is on SalesForce's side for this problem.